# JavaScript: How to highlight text with pressing "Enter/Return"?

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I'm trying to create a functioning search box that highlights words in a text. However,   I cannot make it do the search by pressing Enter. Do you have any suggestions where is the flaw in the code? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="search" onkeypress="if (e.keycode==13) doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doSearch(text)
{
if (window.find && window.getSelection)
   {
document.designMode = "on";
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
while (window.find(text))
      {
document.getElementById("search").blur();
document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "green");
sel.collapseToEnd();
      }
document.designMode = "off";
   }
else if (document.body.createTextRange)
   {
var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
while (textRange.findText(text))
      {
textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "green");
textRange.collapse(false);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what are your specific issues?

Comment: you can't define condition directly. as you will you get e defined?

Comment: @epoch: My specific issue is that it doesn't do the search when I hit enter. It does work with if I use a button and an onmousedown command, but I cannot make it work with onkeypress.

Comment: @DKM: While I was searching for a solution, every answer used this "e.keycode" part, so I thought it belongs there... I guess it was a mistake from me to leave it like that.

Comment: @Zoldkabatos see my answer you can do like that also :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this instead

```
  <input type="text" id="search" onkeypress="if (window.event.keyCode==13) doSearch(this.value);" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
```

No need to use `document.getElementbyId()` as you are in the textbox, simply do `this.value`.

#### **Fiddle DEMO**

Comment: My level is really much lower than that of a monkey :(
http://jsfiddle.net/zoldkabatos/mQpGn/

Comment: @Zoldkabatos What's wrong with that fiddle? See this http://jsfiddle.net/mQpGn/1/, You have an exception with your code somewhere.

Comment: If I press Enter in your code, it doesn't highlight the entered word. If it does for you, it's something with my browser.

Comment: It's not working for me here as i have provided you the hint how you can manupulate through enter key event and call your function. you javascript code gives error in browser, if you want to see, open my fiddle -> right click-> inspect elemet -> console. you will see error

Answer (score 0):

change your event trigger to read as the following

```
<input type="text" id="search" onkeypress="if (window.event.keyCode==13) doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
```

i also recommend using `onkeydown` instead of `onkeypress` because `onkeypress` doesn't detect certain control keys being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery for this? Starts to tidy up the code somewhat, and moves your javascript out of the view.

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '13') {
     e.preventDefault();
     doSearch(this.value);
   }
});
```

Comment: jQuery is not required, don't sell jQuery to people until it's required